# Android XML drawable transparent gradient is not transparent

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create a transparent gradient like in Play Music.

**drawable/shadow_up.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

**layout/main_layout.xml:**

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

                   <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_up"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the gradient is not transparent. How to fix this?

[image]

The gradient from Play Music:

[image]

It transparent.

Comment: do you want the whole gradient to be transparent ?

Comment: Either all or only startColor/endColor transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable answer is that your gradient view does NOT overlap the list view - in other words, the list view is above your gradient, the gradient xml is correct, its the views that are positioned wrong. You should try something more like this

```
<ReltaiveLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  Your litview goes here, with both dimensions match parent

                 <View
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_up"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If the ListView in the fragment, and the fragment loaded into the FrameLayout, then is it possible to get transparent gradient?